# AWS Boto What value for CoreCount to disable hyperthreading?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'd like to create EC2 instances with hyperthreading disabled using Python Boto.

I can see I need to use the CpuOptions argument to `create_instances()`.

However, `CpuOptions` requires two parameters:

```
'CoreCount': 123,
'ThreadsPerCore': 123
```

To disable hyperthreading I know I set `ThreadPerCore` to 1.

However, what do I put for `CoreCount`?

If I create an instance which has 32 Intel vcpus, I'd like just 16 physical cpus.

If I create an instance which has 64 Intel vcpus, I'd like just 32 physical cpus.

What should I set to achieve this?

Surely the core count is dictated by the instance type? If I create a t2micro I can't have 200 cores.